# Can I use google analytics to show users visits on content they have added?

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have a website where users can post their articles. I would like to show them full stats on their content visits, referrers, countries and all the cool stuff that modern counters can offer. Is there a way to implement it using google analytics? Or is there some special system for this? I know that livejournal.com do this, but how?

I can imagine it works like this:

1. On page with articles I pass an additional parameter to counter, like `article id` or something;
2. When user wants to see stats, I make a request through API to get visits for this `article_id`.

Is there a way to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has announced this one, 
[link](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2008/10/more-enterprise-class-features-added-to.html)
http://analytics.blogspot.com/2008/10/more-enterprise-class-features-added-to.html

But i am not sure how it works, i think this will help you.
Once I tried doing this for one of the client, it was not allowing. that time i realised that we need to export the values from google analytics to our local database and show it.